# python - changing existing elements in matrix (without array)

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop, matrix, jupyter-notebook

I am given a matrix of ints and I need to create a function that does the following -
if a number in a cell = 0, the whole column and row needs to change to 0.
but I need to change the original matrix, not allowed to make a copy.

I can use only very basic stuff like list of lists, for, if, split I don't know array or complicated numbers.

I hope you can help me please :)

Comment: Are you using numpy or just a list of lists?

Comment: Can you  check and let me know if it works as you expect, if yes then click accept?